# Adding a getElementById to an jquery .get function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to get from 'page'+i a container div with id = 'posts1', but I'm struggling to add a .getElementById or similar to this function:

```
$.get('page-'+i, function(data){
    content = data;
    $('#posts').append(content);
});
```

I've tried adding it on content, data and putting 'page'+i in brackets and then adding .getElementById but nothing works, i'm always getting that what i'm doing isn't a function or error 500 (Internal Server Error).

**Edit**:
This is the full function:

```
function showMore() {
        if (i<=196) {
            $.get('page-'+i+' #posts' , function(data){
                content = data;
                $('#posts').append(content);
            });
            i++;
        }
```

This is activated on a click of a button.
I need to append, after the existing articles in #posts, more articles that are for ex in page-2 in the div with id 'posts1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found where was my issue:

```js
function showMore() {
  if (i<=196) {
    $.get('page-'+i , function(data) {
      var content = $(data).find('#posts1');
      $('#posts').append(content);
    });
    i++;
  }
}
```

I've added `.find` to my data and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Just a note here - you'll end up with a lot of divs with your posts id inside your original posts div so you might want to just append the children of your content instead: `content.children().appendTo($('#posts'))`

Comment: this code will be further modified because i'm implementing it for an infinite scroll modifying #posts1 for each click adding 1 to it to be like: #posts2, #posts3 etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and .load

If `i` is 1, then this will read a page with filename `page-1` and insert the element from that page with id="post1" into the element with id="posts" on current page

```
$('#posts').load(`page-${i} #post1`)
```

Added to a simpler version of your function

```
function showMore() {
  if (i>196) return;  
  $('#posts').load(`page-${i} #posts`);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: where am i supposed to add this?

Comment: i have existing data on #posts and when i replace with your function it doesn't return anything

Comment: i've updated my question, hoping to be more clear